# Total a Value and Return Value in Same Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

In my **`SQL`** i have a column like this

```
SUM(ISNULL(CAST(A.ODENEN_ANAPARA AS FLOAT),0)+ISNULL(CAST(A.FAIZ AS FLOAT),0)+
      ISNULL(CAST(A.BSMV AS FLOAT),0)+ISNULL(CAST(A.GECIKME_FAIZ AS FLOAT),0)+
      ISNULL(CAST(A.GECIKME_BSMV AS FLOAT),0)) AS 'YATAN'
```

and i have a function getting another value like that;

```
USE [Example]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[fngcodeme]    Script Date: 03/15/2011 11:52:16 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fngcodeme]
(
    @HESAP INT,@BAS DATE, @BIT DATE,@DOV INT
)
RETURNS FLOAT

AS
BEGIN

RETURN( 
    SELECT SUM(TUTAR)
    FROM YAZ..MARDATA.M_GHAREKET
    WHERE TEMEL_HESAP = @HESAP
    AND DOVIZ_KOD = @DOV
    AND REF_KOD = 'GC'
    AND BACAK_GRUP = 'PERT'
    AND ISL_KOD = 1
    AND ISL_TAR >= @BAS 
    AND ISL_TAR <= @BIT
)
END
```

What i want is total of first SQL and function on same column.

(Example: "Yatan" is A, Function return value is B, I want one colum A + B)

**`Best Regards, Soner`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
   SUM(ISNULL(CAST(A.ODENEN_ANAPARA AS FLOAT),0)+ISNULL(CAST(A.FAIZ AS FLOAT),0)+
      ISNULL(CAST(A.BSMV AS FLOAT),0)+ISNULL(CAST(A.GECIKME_FAIZ AS FLOAT),0)+
      ISNULL(CAST(A.GECIKME_BSMV AS FLOAT),0)) 
   + dbo.fngcodeme(@HESAP,@BAS,@BIT,@DOV)
from ...
```

Comment: @BAS is Start Date, @BIT is Finish Date. In my page i select two Textbox for this dates. Like this pic http://i1103.hizliresim.com/2011/3/15/5030.jpg And i use this code if (txtBoxText1 != ""){strQuery = strQuery + " AND A.ISL_TAR >= @S_TARIH_B"; 
      dt_stb = DateTime.Parse(txtBoxText1);
      myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@S_TARIH_B", dt_stb);}
    if (txtBoxText2 != "")
    { strQuery = strQuery + " AND A.ISL_TAR <= @S_TARIH_S";
      dt_sts = DateTime.Parse(txtBoxText2);
      myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@S_TARIH_S", dt_sts); How can i set it function? (Start, end date)

Comment: Because this code doesn't work SUM(ISNULL(CAST(A.ODENEN_ANAPARA AS FLOAT),0)+ISNULL(CAST(A.FAIZ AS FLOAT),0)+
      ISNULL(CAST(A.BSMV AS FLOAT),0)+ISNULL(CAST(A.GECIKME_FAIZ AS FLOAT),0)+
      ISNULL(CAST(A.GECIKME_BSMV AS FLOAT),0)) + [dbo].[fngcodeme](@B.HESAP_NO, @S_TARIH_B, @S_TARIH_S, @B.DOVIZ_KOD)  AS 'YATAN'